# Confidence interval for the difference between $X_1$ and $X_2$ or $X_3$

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

The question:

> Find a 99% confidence interval for the difference in mean oxygen
>   consumption of an algae that is in 100% concentrated seawater with
>   algae that is not in 100% seawater (i.e., 50% or 75%).

Is this the correct approach?

> If we let $X_1$ be the random variable corresponding to the mean
>   oxygen consumption for algae in 100% seawater, $X_2$ for 50% and $X_3$
>   for 75% then I want to find the standard error of $X_1+\frac{X_2+X_3}{2}$.

If so, I know how to proceed from there. Otherwise, I don't know how to start this.

Comment: What do the data look like?

Comment: @whuber we just have 8 numerical data for 100% and 4 entries for 50% and 75% each. The question is the second part of a question about ANOVA analysis if that helps. I'm just not sure how to make one confidence interval for two differences. or is it asking for multiple confidence intervals?

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of there being a response on this question:

It looks to me like it's asking for a single interval of the type you were thinking of when you wrote the attempted solution:

> If we let $X_1$ be the random variable corresponding to the mean
>   oxygen consumption for algae in 100% seawater, $X_2$ for 50% and $X_3$
>   for 75% then I want to find the standard error of $X_1+\frac{X_2+X_3}{2}$.

However, you have a sign error in that expression at the end there; the "+" after $X_1$ should be "-". The question asks for:

> confidence interval for the *difference* in mean oxygen consumption

so you need the standard error of an estimate of the contrast $\mu_1-\frac{\mu_2+\mu_3}{2}$ (i.e. difference), which you'd form from the relevant sample means. Personally I'd denote those by $\bar X_i$ rather than $X_i$, to emphasize that we're dealing with group means.

Otherwise, you seem to have basically the right sense of the problem.